# Fill the intersection of 3 (or more) curves

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

I couldn't find a simple way to fill the area of the intersections of 3 curves. I want to fill this area:

[image]

My try:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotsset{my style1/.append style={clip = false, axis lines* = middle, axis equal, xtick = \empty, ytick = \empty}}

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, math, positioning, arrows, intersections} 
 
\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[my style1, samples=150]
        \addplot [domain=0:1.5, name path=c1] ({x},{x^2+0.2});
        \addplot [domain=0:1.5, name path=c2] ({x},{sqrt(x)+0.2});
        \addplot [name path=c3] coordinates {(0.3,0.5)(1.3,0.5)(1.3,0.9)(0.3,0.9)(0.3,0.5)};
        %\addplot [blue] fill between[of=c1,c2 and c3];
        
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

But it seems like fill between only can fill the intersection of 2 curves. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the `soft clip` option from `pgfplots` is not sufficient here, hence I use a `\fill` following `\clip`.

Full example

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotsset{my style1/.append style={clip = false, axis lines* = middle, axis equal, xtick = \empty, ytick = \empty}}

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, math, positioning, arrows, intersections} 
 
\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[my style1, samples=150]
        \addplot [domain=0:1.5, name path=c1] ({x},{x^2+0.2});
        \addplot [domain=0:1.5, name path=c2] ({x},{sqrt(x)+0.2});
        \addplot [name path=c3] coordinates {(0.3,0.5)(1.3,0.5)(1.3,0.9)(0.3,0.9)(0.3,0.5)};
        
        % \clip will act on all the following paths in the current scope
        \clip (.3,.5) rectangle (1.3,.9);
        \fill[blue] (0, 0) plot[domain=0:1.5] (\x, \x^2+.2) 
                        -- plot[domain=1.5:0] (\x, {sqrt(\x)+.2}) -- (0, 0);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The left corner is supposed to be fill. And you said a thing that is not coherent: pgf v3.1.6 contains a problem  but v3.1.6 has fixed this problem

Comment: @Iborra Looks like `soft clip` is not sufficient here. And the second v3.1.6 should be v3.1.6a. I will delete this answer.

Comment: @Iborra My answers is updated and a `tikz` workaround is provided.

Comment: The initial (0,0) and the final -- (0,0) are unnecesary